# Date selection with Codeception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, codeception

Here is my problem, i need to make it somehow, with Codeception, so it selects a date. The Images will make everything clear.

[image]

You can see that i need the program to select the date in the drop down, the problem is that the dropdown items, so the years and so forth don't have any id that i can talk to.

I Tried with `$I-> Click/fillField` , but i really cant get to the result that i want.

Any input is welcome.

Danke

Comment: You really haven't provided enough information. Did you really try exactly "$I-> Click/fillField", what did you expect it to do? You need to find out more information about the thing you're trying to click. It has no ids or classes?

Comment: Edit your question and add code you have tried, add html snippet of the element if possible, add stack trace of the error if you are getting one.

Answer (score 4):

If anyone will ever need this.
This is how i made it work:

```
$I->executeJS("$('#ENTERIDHERE').val('1969-01-02');");
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you get the node with your actual selector you can also select an specific sub-node.
The usage of `$I->click()` or `$I->fillField()` is right, even if i would prefer to use `$I->click()` in this cause, 'cause that is what the user would to.

Next you have to get the rigth selector. In this case XPath and [the codeception Locator-class](http://codeception.com/docs/reference/Locator) should work fine.

I'm sorry, that I cant tell you, how the XPAth locator would looks like. Please provide the Sourcecode for further help.